# About "alter session set container = orclpdb" in Oracle 19c

Tags: sql, oracle

Greeting folks;

Just installed `Oracle 19c` on my laptop (`Win10 64bit`). Below is what I did:

- Step1: Login SQL plus as `SYS AS SYSDBA`
- Step2: Run the statement `alter session set container = orclpdb;`
- Step3: Create a user, some tables, and insert some data into the tables.

Within the session, I can query the tables and see the results. But when I logged out and re-logged in, I don't see the tables anymore. I must run the statement `alter session set container = orclpdb;`, then I could see the tables.

I couldn't create a user without running the `Alter session...` statement. I got the below error:

```
SQL> CREATE USER tester IDENTIFIED BY tester;

CREATE USER tester IDENTIFIED BY tester
            *
ERROR at line 1:

ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
```

I just want to see the tables without running the statement `alter session set container = orclpdb;`, what should I do?

Thank you!

---

Bach,

Thanks for the info. It's my fault, I really meant to create a user not a table.

Below is exactly what I want in the 2nd link:

UNDOCUMENTED If you really, really, really want to create a user that can log into ANY database (not just the root database, but an actual global user) but without the “C##” prefix, you can change an underscore parameter:

alter system set "_common_user_prefix" = '' scope=spfile;

If you do that, and reboot your database, you’ll be allowed to create a global user without the C## prefix.

grant dba to kaley identified by ThisIsMyPassword container = all;

Comment: Then simply skip step2 and do step1, step3. And as you use CDB, you should read [doc](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-connecting-to-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1) to know which cdb/ pdb you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

As your edited post, you are create a user (schema), not table.

When you create user in CDB not PDB, you have to create a [common user](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-DA54EBE5-43EF-4B09-B8CC-FAABA335FBB8.htm#:%7E:text=A%20common%20user%20is%20a,%2Dsupplied%20or%20user%2Dcreated.) (start with C##, can exists for both CDB and all PDBs).

So either you change user to C##tester, or you should switch to pdb `orclpdb` as your `ALTER SESION` statement to create a user only for that PDB.

And your problem is that you're not yet familier with new Oracle CDB, you should read more doc about that.

Comment: You can find more information here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/CDBs-and-PDBs.html